# nginx how to serve 'admin' subdomain request fro a specific root folder?

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to serve all requests to example.com ( and www.example.co) 
from the root folder

```
location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

but all requests to admin.example.com from a another folder 'admin' on the same server  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `admin.example.com` should be configured as a separate `server` in nginx config, but noone restricts you from pointing its root inside other server's root directory

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name admin.example.com;
  root /some/path/example.com/admin;

  location / {
    index index.html;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  root /some/path/example.com;
  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different server directives, this way:

```
server {
    server_name admin.example.com;

    root   admin;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

}

server {
    server_name example.com;

    root   html;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Also, it is better to use only one `root` directive at server level, not to repeat it across `location` blocks (cf [pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block)).